# Mandating "in-place" construction

Tags: c++

Simple enough code where `bar` has a member of type `foo`:

```
struct foo {
  foo(int some, int parameters) {}
};

struct bar {
  foo f;
  bar(foo f_) { f = f_; }
}
```

How do I change it so that `bar` can **only** be initialized with a `foo` "in-place", e.g. like this?

```
foo f;
bar b1(f); //error
bar b2(1,2); //works!
```

The purpose is that sometimes I'm dealing with classes `foo` that cannot be copied and doing it this way would make intent clear.

Comment: then why not make `foo`'s copy constructor private?

Comment: C++11 perfect forwarding. I'll let others expand on that, I haven't got enough time right now to make it a fully-fledged answer. :-(

Comment: @syam so i take it that the "emplace" functions use this "perfect forwarding" thing under the hood?

Comment: @7cows: indeed, that's how it works.

Comment: Maybe simply: `bar(int a, int b) : f(a, b) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @KerrekSB mentioned, the easiest way is to replicate `foo`'s constructors in `bar`:

```
bar(int a, int b) : f(a, b) {}
```

However this quickly becomes impractical when `foo` has a large number of constructors, and it may even be impossible if `bar` is a `template<typename T>` and you want to do this for any possible `T`.

---

Enter C++11's **perfect forwarding**:

```
template<typename... Args>
bar(Args&&... args) : f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

This allows your `bar` constructor to forward any arguments it receives directly to the `foo` constructor, just like the `emplace` methods in the C++11 Standard Library.

---

Now there's still a catch: since your `bar` constructor accepts *any* arguments that your `foo` constructor accepts, obviously if `foo` has a copy constructor then `bar` will accept it:

```
bar b1(1, 2); // ok
foo f(1, 2);
bar b2(f);    // ok too!
```

The trick is to delete the relevant constructors:

```
struct bar {
    foo f;

    template<typename... Args>
    bar(Args&&... args) : f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    bar(const foo&) = delete;
    bar(foo&) = delete;
};

foo f(1, 2);
bar b2(f);    // error: use of deleted function ‘bar::bar(foo&)’
```

Note that I purposely didn't delete the move constructor because I assume that your motivation for disabling copy is performance. This way you can still write:

```
foo f(1, 2);
bar b1(std::move(f)); // move: ok
bar b2(foo(1, 2));    // temporary: ok (it is really moved)
```

Of course if you want to delete the move constructor too it's very straightforward:

```
struct bar {
    foo f;

    template<typename... Args>
    bar(Args&&... args) : f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    bar(const foo&) = delete;
    bar(foo&) = delete;
    bar(foo&&) = delete;
};

foo f(1, 2);
bar b1(std::move(f)); // error: use of deleted function ‘bar::bar(foo&&)’
bar b2(foo(1, 2));    // error: use of deleted function ‘bar::bar(foo&&)’
```

---

**Idiosyncrasy:** I don't know why but even with a deleted move constructor in `bar`, it still accepts a temporary that is default-constructed (GCC 4.7):

```
bar b3(foo()); // WTH, this works
```

There has to be a good reason I missed, but I have no idea what really happens here. If anyone can shed some light on this...

Comment: GCC 4.8 is out now. And GCC 4.9 at the bleeding edge supports inheriting constructors, which takes care of the perfect forwarding for you, with `using bar::bar;`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Inherited constructors are fine for inheriting constructors *from the base class*. Here we are dealing with composition, `bar` must forward its constructor's arguments to its member `f` so we can't use inherited constructors.